# Request.Querystring is null when use unit test

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing

I want to create Nunit test case for ASP.NET MVC application. If the ASP.NET uses Request.QueryString or Request.Url. then the unit test case will return null reference exception since the Request.querystring will return the value if the control comes from UI only.

So can you please help on this to create a unit test for MVC controller which uses Httpcontext.Request attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your unit test runs outside of the HttpContext and therefore you either need to mock the HttpContext or change your architecture to work around the problem, an example of this is shown below:

http://volaresystems.com/Blog/post/Dont-mock-HttpContext.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your update Burt. Can you please let me know the namespace to use the mock concepts?

Comment: Have a read at this article it will go into a lot more depth on the subject that I can: http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/a-testing-perspective-of-controllers-and-orchestrators/

Comment: Hi Burt,
Thanks for the update. My controller sample code is as below.
**public ActionResults index()
{
if(Request.Url.ToString()=="www.abc.com")
{
return RedirecttoAction("About");
}
return View();
}**

Unit Test Code is as follows:
**[Test]
public void testIndex(){
SampleController controller = new SampleController();
 ActionResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;}**
When the control goes to Request.URL the null reference exception throws.
**Can you please let me know how to initialize the Request.URL or Request.QueryString values from unit test project?**

Comment: You need to mock out the dependencies e.g. you shouldn't be calling Request.Anything from code under test. If you put that code behind an interface you could mock the call and give whatever return result you want to enable you to test your code.

Comment: Hi Burt,
Thanks for your help.
Can you please give me the example for mock with interface?

Comment: Here is an example mocking framework - http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-mocks

Comment: Hi Burt, Thank you for your help. Can you please let me know what are the things neeed to be moved to interface? it could be Request.URL or Request.Anything related query?

Comment: Do we need to unit test the each line of code within the action?

Comment: You would normally test the boundary conditions and the different paths through the code and any exceptions

Comment: Can we initialize httpcontext.current.Request?

Comment: Hi Burt,
Can we unit test the action which are having access specifier as private? If possible how can we unit test the private actions?